# Does Dojo have an equivalent to jQuery.trigger()?

Tags: jquery, events, dojo

In jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('#myElement').trigger('change');
```

How do I do that in Dojo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Dojo has similar functionality, at least as not as far as I know / can find. But you can use code like the following to replicate this functionality:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    var button = dojo.byId("myButton");
    dojo.connect(button, "onclick", function() { alert("Clicked!"); });

    // IE does things differently
    if (dojo.isIE)
    {
        button.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
    else
    { // Not IE
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("click", false, true);
        console.debug(event);
        button.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

A little more verbose, for sure, but you would be able to create your own Dojo version of trigger() with it.

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/SecLC/1/)

Comment: This kind of issue makes me miss jQuery's sheer simplicity.. :p

Comment: yes, in the same way a car is 'absurd and difficult' compared to a bicycle

Answer (score 38):

The dojo [on.emit](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html#emit) method (1.7+) can be used to trigger an event on a dom node.  From the documentation page:

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
    // register event handler
    on(target, "mouseup", function(e){
        // handle event
    });

    // Send event
    on.emit(target, "mouseup", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this functionality is only available since version 1.7.

Comment: Also, passing an object (even if empty) is mandatory for the third argument.

Comment: Can't seem to get the sending portion of the even to actually trigger it. Could you provide a fiddle by chance?

Comment: Okay, figured out the problem. 'Target' HAS to be a DOM node itself, not a dijit instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For certain dijit widgets and djit specific events ( such as onChange ), you can de-facto 'trigger' by calling the event name.

```
<input id="numberBox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" /> 

<script>
    dojo.connect( dijit.byId('numberBox'), "onChange", function ( event ) { 
        dijit.byId('numberBox').set('value', 12345 );
    }); 

    dijit.byId('numberBox').onChange();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled upon Dojo's publish/subscribe mechanism, and I think this is the counterpart to jQuery's bind/trigger.

Links:

- [Events with Dojo (v1.6)](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/events/)
- [`dojo.publish` reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/publish.html)

Answer (score 1):

PlugD has `dojo.trigger` and more: https://github.com/phiggins42/plugd

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can trigger an event on a DOM element in Dojo like this:

```
dojo.byId("myElement").onChange();
```

Comment: Actually it is. I only wanted to say, that dojo is not so absurd and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the last comment, access dijit as pure DOM Object via dom API.

```js
require(["dojo/dom",
        'dojo/on',
        "dojo/domReady!"], function (dom, on) {

        //Does not work
        //registry.byId('myButton') 
        //registry.byId('myButton').domNode
  
        //Proper way
        on.emit(dom.byId('myButton'), "click", {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true
        });

});
```