# Is there a "onExpand" event or similar for dijit.TitlePane?

Tags: dojo

Is there any way to get an event callback when the dojo-dijit's TitlePane expands?

I can capture onClick on the TitlePane. However, that is not enough for me. I have a button for "Expand All" TitlePanes. When user clicks on that I iterate on all TitlePanes and call it's toggle() method. When that happens, onClick event is not fired (as expected). I was wondering if there is any event fired upon toggle().

Or any other smart ways to address it also will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into documentation in detail, I do not think there is any built in event that is fired during the toggle/expand. I ended up firing a custom event, and that helped me get what I wanted.

This answer helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852043/3810374

Basically,

First using isOpen() method, ensure the title pane is not already expanded. Then call toggle() method, and fire a custom event like this:

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  // Send event
  on.emit(target, "onExpand", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
});
```

And then handle the event:

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  // register event handler
  on(target, "onExpand", function(e){
      // handle event
  });
});
```

You may be wondering, why not just do the work right after toggle(), instead of going through the pain of firing/handling event. I needed to handle the event in a particular closure, where I have access to other objects and variables.