# Automating Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

We are doing the automation of this web site that uses DOJO Framework:
[Movistar](https://online.movistar.com.ar/autogestion/loadSelectLocationAction.do)

My question is over the functionallity of this framework, if it is events based.

How can i automate the menu with javascript when selected "Capital Federal, Capital Federal"?, i am trying send a click to the events listener (by the way, i am generating a click onto menu) , but not works fine.

i am grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to create a click handler on a menu item, but you're question is very broad, so you might want to consider adding more details.

You might have something like this:

```
require(['dijit/Menu', 'dijit/MenuItem'], function(Menu, MenuItem){
    var menu = new Menu({
        targetNodeIds: ["menuNode"]
    });
    menu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Capital Federal",
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
        onClick: function(){
            alert('i was clicked')
        }
    }));
});
```

Source: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html

Comment: no, i am trying to generate a click into the option

Answer (score 0):

When you say "We are doing the automation", do you mean automation of testing?
If so what tool or language are you using to do that?

To answer your question if it is event based. yes it has events, similar to the regular html controls. the details are provided in there api documentation http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_MenuItem_onClick

There are couple of ways to trigger the dojo event in javascript. The post should provide you with more details.
[Does Dojo have an equivalent to jQuery.trigger()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002478/does-dojo-have-an-equivalent-to-jquery-trigger)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: i am trying generate a mouse down event with javascript in an option of the menú

Comment: So you are trying to open the popup menu programatically. To be able to raise a event you need to use dojo.on.emit. Here I have created a jsBin showing the same. http://jsbin.com/xilaqaxiwa/11/edit?html,output.   there are other ways to show the menu programatically like if the dijit implements _hasDropDown.js then you could use openDrowDown method or if its a popup menu you could use dijit/popup

Comment: I have not access to the code, i am using QTP to test this control.